# Changing Parameter on the page based on entering another parameter?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project where at first, I will choose which parameter I want to calculate with:

```
<select name="way" id="choice">
  <option value="rH" selected>relative Humidity</option>
  <option value="Tdp">Dewpoint</option>
  <option value="ppm">ppm</option>
</select>
```

Then you will enter the temperature, the pressure and one of the parameters you chose from above into text fields to calculate a result.

```
<input id="temp" type="text">
<input id="press" type="text">
<input id="para" type="text">???
```

Each different parameter has a different calculation formula leading to a different parameter(result). How can I do it with Javascript?
Thanks!

Comment: Get the value of the `select`, then use either `if/then` or `switch/case` to execute different code depending on which option they selected.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? If so, what step are you stuck on?
Try to breakdown this problem to smaller, more precise problems.

Comment: I am really new in html and I doesn't really know how I could solve the problem. I thought about getting the value of select, but I'm not sure what I should do with it...  <script type="text/javascript">
                        function choose(){
                            var choice1 = document.getElementById("choice").value;
                            if (choice1 == "rF") {
                            }
                        }
                    </script>

Comment: Try to write down different scenarios in english, and then try to translate that in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to detect the change when user changed the `<select>` and based on you logic you can manipulate the DOM or apply your business logic. In the following example I have implemented show/hide of div based on user's selection. In similar fashion you can implement your own logic.

```js
function choose(option) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.input-wrap').forEach(function(el) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  });
  switch (option) {
    case "Tdp":
      var temp = document.getElementsByClassName("temp-wrap");
      temp[0].style.display = "block";
      break;
    case "ppm":
      var press = document.getElementsByClassName("press-wrap");
      press[0].style.display = "block";
      break;
    case "rH":
      var para = document.getElementsByClassName("para-wrap");
      para[0].style.display = "block";
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="way" id="choice" onchange="choose(this.value)">
  <option value="rH" selected>relative Humidity</option>
  <option value="Tdp">Dewpoint</option>
  <option value="ppm">ppm</option>
</select>

<div class="input-wrap temp-wrap" style="display:none;">
  <label>Temperatur</label>
  <input id="temp" type="text">
</div>
<div class="input-wrap press-wrap" style="display:none;">
  <label>Press</label>
  <input id="press" type="text">
</div>
<div class="input-wrap para-wrap" style="display:none;">
  <label>Para</label>
  <input id="para" type="text">
</div>
```